# How to check null value in MVC view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC with LINQ-to-SQL class.

as foreign key can be null, i have one record having f.k. null and others are having values.

now i am displaying it in view by Index view.

In index view i am resolving f.k. by writing code like

```
<%= Html.Encode(item.UserModified.UserName) %>
```

Now i have a problem in view that "object reference is not set".

And this is because of we are having null value in one of the f.k. field!

so can i write code in view to check whether Associated object pointing to null or nothing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write any code you want in the view if necessary, so you could do:

```
<%= Html.Encode(item.UserModified.UserName ?? string.Empty) %>
```

You could also make a HtmlHelper extension to do this:

```
public string SafeEncode(this HtmlHelper helper, string valueToEncode)
{
    return helper.Encode(valueToEncode ?? string.Empty);
}
```

You could then simply do:

```
<%= Html.SafeEncode(item.UserModified.UserName) %>
```

Of course if it's UserModified that's null and not UserName then you'll need some different logic.

Answer (score 1):

With C#, you can use the conditional operator:

```
<%= Html.Encode(item.UserModified == null ? "" : item.UserModified.UserName) %>
```

However, it might be a better choice to move the UserName property to be a direct child of item, or to put it in ViewData.

Answer (score 0):

First consider whether in your model an instance of User is valid without Name. If no then you should put a guard clause in the constructor.

Secondly, too many and duplicated null checks is a code smell. You should use the refactoring [Replace Conditional with Polymorphism](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html). You can create a Null object according to the [Null Object Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/null_object).

This will make sure that you do not have to check for Null everywhere.